# How can I create a registry value and path leading to it in one line using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, registry

Creating a registry value, including the path up to it, and not erroring if the path already exists is easy using old-school reg.exe:

```
reg add HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\EdgeUI /f /v DisableHelpSticker /t reg_sz /d 1
```

That's nice and concise. The shortest way I found to do it in pure PowerShell is two lines, or three if you don't want to repeat the path:

```
$regPath = 'HKCU:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\EdgeUI'
New-Item $regPath -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty $regPath -Name DisableHelpSticker -Value 1 -Force | Out-Null
```

Is there an easier way using pure PowerShell? And without adding a utility function.

Comment: not that it matters, but you can suppress the error that occurs when a key does exist by testing path first.  See the `if -not test-path` portion of this answer.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/26707878/3093031

Comment: That's true. But then it's even bigger. I was using either `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` or `-Force` to avoid the error.

Comment: Do you really, absolutely, have to, have everything on one line? Even looking at your examples, the three lines of Powershell are more readable than your one line of reg.exe

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Another way of simplifying PS registry handling is calling the .Net function **SetValue()** directly:

```
[microsoft.win32.registry]::SetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Test", "Test-String", "Testing")
[microsoft.win32.registry]::SetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Test", "Test-DW", 0xff)
```

Comment: Works. The arguments to SetValue are: `SetValue(basePath, keyName, keyValue)`. Note that if `basePath` includes intermediary paths (folder?) that don't exist, they will be created. For example, for "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\One\Two" and path "One" doesn't exist, "One" and "Two" will be created.

Answer (score 34):

You can pipe the creation line to the `New-ItemProperty` line as follows, but be aware that the `-Force` flag on `New-Item` will delete any pre-existing contents of the key:

```powershell
New-Item 'HKCU:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\EdgeUI' -Force | New-ItemProperty -Name DisableHelpSticker -Value 1 -Force | Out-Null
```

Comment: I just learned that New-Item's `-Force` flag blows away all sub-keys/values. `-SilentlyContinue` doesn't retrieve the object. I'm trying to think of an easy way to set a value non-destructively, creating the path if it doesn't exist, in a single line with no "if key exists..." type of thing. Because that's getting silly for a one-liner. Let me know if you have any ideas.

Comment: You could use `Test-Path` to check the existence of they key before trying to create it, if it does exist check for the property too. Would be worth putting into a function if you're doing it multiple times.

Comment: I'm starting to think that's the option to "overlay" data into the registry, and there's no nice one-liner.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't have any luck with @mschomm's answer for setting a DWORD value. Finally got this code to work for me:

```
$RegName = '2233969290'
$RegPath = 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Policies\Microsoft\FeatureManagement\Overrides\'
$RegData = 0  

Write-Output "Setting Registry Key"    
[microsoft.win32.registry]::SetValue($RegPath, $RegName, $RegData, [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind]::DWORD)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the following:

```
New-ItemProperty -Path Registry::HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\EdgeUI -Name DisableHelpSticker -Value Contoso -Force | Out-Null
```

I am using this for some SCCM stuff and it doesn't overwrite my existing reg entries.

Comment: This command will not create 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\EdgeUI' if it don't exist and regardless of using | Out-Null, error will still be show at the console.

Comment: Ahh, didnt see the 'and path leading up to it'.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another one-liner:

`'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\NamingTemplates' | % { if (Test-Path $_) { Get-Item $_ } else { New-Item $_ } } | Set-ItemProperty -Name 'RenameNameTemplate' -Value (Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd')`

This sample sets the default name of a new explorer folder to the current date. I run this one in a scheduled task at 00:00h every day.