# Creating Registry entries with PowerShell: Custom object, Registry Object, or separate statements?

Tags: powershell, registry

I am attempting to write a PowerShell script that will create a bunch of registry entries.  I have been doing some Googling as well as searching StackOverflow to find how other people are accomplishing this task.  It seems most people are resorting to using `New-Item` and `New-ItemProperty` and the like (e.g. this SO question [Creating Registry Keys with Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26707029))

Having more experience with other coding/scripting languages, my thought process would be to create a collection of objects and then import them all with one statement or loop over them, inserting each one individually.

Pseudo-code:

```
$keys_to_import = {
    key1: {
        property1: value1,
        property2: value2,
    },
    key2: {
        property1: value1,
        property2: value2,
    },
    ...
}

Import $keys_to_import

# or

For $key in ($keys_to_import) {
    Import $key
}
```

Is it possible to create/import registry values en masse in this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could for instance create a CSV file with all keys and properties you need to create.
Scalar properties can be added as-is, but for MultiString and Binary values you will have to use some way of putting those in the CSV.

I have chosen these formats:

- MultiString : Separate the different strings using delimiter `;` so the code can split on that creating a string array
- Binary: Write all bytes as Hex digits as string. For instance value `A Binary Value` becomes `412042696E6172792056616C7565`

The CSV file then looks like:

```
"Key","Property","Value","Type"
"HKCU:\SOFTWARE\123\Test","MyStringProperty","A String","String"
"HKCU:\SOFTWARE\123\Test","MyDWordProperty","123","DWord"
"HKCU:\SOFTWARE\123\Test","MyQWordProperty","9223372036854775807","QWord"
"HKCU:\SOFTWARE\123\Test","MyBinaryProperty","412042696E6172792056616C7565","Binary"
"HKCU:\SOFTWARE\123\Test","MyMultiStringProperty","String1;String2;String3","MultiString"
"HKCU:\SOFTWARE\123\Test","MyExpandStringProperty","%SystemRoot%\inf","ExpandString"
```

Use it like this:

```
Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\NewRegs.csv' | ForEach-Object { 
    # see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-itemproperty
    #     --> Parameters --> Type
    $regType = 'String'  # default to type String
    if ('String','ExpandString','DWord','Qword', 'MultiString', 'Binary' -contains $_.Type) {
        $regType = $_.Type
    }

    # depending on the type of the property, determine the correct value
    $value = $_.Value
    $value = switch ($regType) {
        'DWord'       { [int]$value ; break }
        'QWord'       { [int64]$value ; break }
        'MultiString' { [string[]]($value -split ';') ; break }
        'Binary'      { [byte[]]($value -split '(.{2})' -ne '' -replace '^', '0X') ; break }
        default       { $value }
    }

    # test if the key already exists and if not create it
    if (!(Test-Path -Path $_.Key -PathType Container)) {
        $null = New-Item -Path $_.Key -ItemType RegistryKey -Force
    }
    Set-ItemProperty -Path $_.Key -Name $_.Property -Value $value -Type $regType -Force
}
```

Comment: This is a fascinating approach.  Most of the values I think I will be working with should be simple string values.  I'm going to give this a try later and see how it goes.  Thank you!